# How to where do i process my data with observable .map and .subscribe

Tags: http, angular, reactive-programming, rxjs

I'm retriving some data from my API:

```
[
 {
   "id": 1,
   "lat": 50.607084,
   "lng": 3.043099
 },
 {
   "id": 2,
   "lat": 50.607084,
   "lng": 3.043099   
 },
]
```

I'd like to process the data only with reactive programing so that inside my request, google map markers get created.

```
  this.http.get('http://api/getData')
        .map(res => {
          return res.json()
        })
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            console.log(data);
   });
```

when doing this i'm getting a lot of objects, i could not fin a way to log or isolate only the latitude (i get "unknown").

I'd like to be able to put a function inside the ".map" (observable ?) that will get all variable, 
and create markersOptions that i'll put in an array.

```
let markerOptions: GoogleMapsMarkerOptions = {
            position: latlng,
            title: 'id'
};
```

From wath i've seen on google, most of people prefer put the object in a private variable and i assume take care of it, in an other function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is mapping the array retrieved from the server to a list of GoogleMapsMarkerOptions. So, (I don't know the constructor of GoogleMapsMarkerOptions) something like:

```
this.http.get('http://api/getData')
    .map(res => {
      return res.json().map(x => {
         return new GoogleMapsMarkerOptions({
             title: x.it,
             position: new GoogleMapsLatLng(x.lat, x.lng)
         });
      });

    })
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);
});
```

The second map is a standard javascript method (not rxjs). If you need to support old browsers you can use lodash or underscore.